# Вывести все неверные значения в alert

Tags: javascript

Наверное это легко, но я затроил на этом.
Есть функция, в ней считаются верные ответы, выводится их количество, а потом нужно вывести ошибки, например: Правильных ответов 2, неправильные ответы 3, 4, 5.

```
    var vern = 0;

    var a = document.getElementById("img1").style.left;
    a = parseInt(a);
    if (a > 530 && a < 650) {vern++}

    var b = document.getElementById("img2").style.left;
    b = parseInt(b);
    if (b > 1370 && b < 1500) {vern++}

    var c = document.getElementById("img3").style.left;
    c = parseInt(c);
    if (c > 1080 && c < 1220) {vern++}

    var d = document.getElementById("img4").style.left;
    d = parseInt(d);
    if (d > 245 && d < 375) {vern++}

    var e = document.getElementById("img5").style.left;
    e = parseInt(e);
    if (e > 810 && e < 940) {vern++}

    alert("Правильных ответов: " + vern + ". " + "Ошибки в картинках под номером: ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Гооврят, если для множества однотипных действий писать универсальный код, а не копировать кучу строк, то жизнь разработчика становится проще.

```js
let items = [
      { id: 'img1', min: 530,  max: 650 },
      { id: 'img2', min: 1370, max: 1500 },
      { id: 'img3', min: 1080, max: 1220 },
      { id: 'img4', min: 245,  max: 375 },
      { id: 'img5', min: 810,  max: 940 },      
    ];
    
let result = items.reduce(function(acc,v, idx){
                let img = document.getElementById(v.id);
                let l = parseInt(img.style.left);
                
                if(l > v.min && l < v.max) acc.count++;
                else acc.wrong.push(idx);
                
                return acc;
              }, { wrong: [], count: 0 });
              
console.log(result);
```